# doesn't pass return value of function to variable, why?

Tags: c

void reversefunction( const char  *argv2, const char *argv3){

```
FILE *stream1=NULL;
FILE *stream2=NULL;

byteone table[HEADERLENGTH];
byteone numberofchannels;
byteone movebytes;

bytefour i;
bytefour sizeofdata;
bytefour var_towrite_infile;

stream1=fopen(argv2,"rb");
stream2=fopen(argv3,"wb+");

if(stream1==NULL){
    printf("\n.xX!- failed - to - open - file -!Xx.\n");
    exit(0);
}

if(stream2==NULL){
    printf("\n.xX!- failed - to - create - new - file -!Xx.\n");
    exit(0);
}

printf(".xX!- %s - opened - success -!Xx.\n",argv2);

fread(table,1,HEADERLENGTH,stream1);
```

//here starts the problem

```
numberofchannels=little_endian_to_bytefour((table+22),NUMCHANNELS);
sizeofdata=little_endian_to_bytefour((table+40),SUBCHUNK2SIZE);
```

//here ends the problem

```
fwrite(table,1,HEADERLENGTH,stream2);

movebytes=numberofchannels*2;

i=sizeofdata;
fseek(stream1,i,SEEK_SET);

while(i>=0){
    fread(&var_towrite_infile,4,movebytes,stream1);
    fwrite(&var_towrite_infile,4,movebytes,stream2);
    i=i-movebytes;
    fseek(stream1,i,SEEK_SET);
    printf("%d\n",i);
    printf("%d\n",sizeofdata);
    printf("%d\n",little_endian_to_bytefour((table+40),SUBCHUNK2SIZE));
    printf("-------------\n");
}

fclose(stream1);
fclose(stream2);
return;
```

}

So, when i'm trying to pass in variables numberofchannels and sizeofdata the return value of function little_endian_to_bytefour it doesn't pass nothing.And when i print the return value, it prints it correct. So why this happens ?

//screen of terminal

```
.
.
.

0
0
113920
-------------
0
0
113920
-------------
0
0
113920
-------------

.
.
.
```

//end of screen terminal

//additional imformation

```
typedef unsigned char byteone;

typedef unsigned short int bytetwo;

typedef unsigned int bytefour;



bytefour little_endian_to_bytefour(byteone *table, byteone bit_length){

    bytefour number=0;

    if(bit_length==2){
        number=table[1];
        number<<=8;
        number|=table[0];
    }
    else{
        number=table[3];
        number<<=8;
        number|=table[2];
        number<<=8;
        number|=table[1];
        number<<=8;
        number|=table[0];
    }

    return number;

}
```

small example/*

```
int myfunction(int var1, int var2)
{

  int var3;

  var3=var1+var2

  return var3;

}

int main(void){

  int zaza1;

  zaza1=myfunction(2,3);

  printf("the number is %d",zaza1);

return;
}
```

//terminal

the number is 0

//end of terminal

*/

Comment: Can you create a small example which recreates this issue without adding any extra code that is not related to the current problem?

Comment: @Mike What undefined behavior are you referring to?

Comment: How is `HEADERLENGTH` defined?  A small, standalone compile-able example would be useful (although since this deals with an external input file you would have to include that too).

Comment: The definition of `SUBCHUNK2SIZE` would also be helpful.

Comment: the small example is something like that

Comment: # define HEADERLENGTH 44

# define SUBCHUNK2SIZE 4

Comment: The small example actually fails as shown?

Comment: Please clarify this: "So, when i'm trying to pass in variables numberofchannels and sizeofdata the return value of function little_endian_to_bytefour it doesn't pass nothing." What is expected, and what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You probably confused between `var3` that you declare & return in your `myfunction`, and the `arg3` that gets the value of `var1+var2`.

That is, you return an uninitialized variable `var3`, which is just in case 0.

Comment: no no the small example is false i made it right now before i check it! 

sorry! ill fix it right now!!!!

Comment: The small example has a typo (missing ";"); if I fix that and compile with all warnings, I get a number of warnings, and then running it prints "the number is 5" (with no terminating newline).  Recommended: turn on all available warnings in your compiler.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef unsigned char byteone;
typedef unsigned int bytefour;

bytefour little_endian_to_bytefour(byteone *table, byteone bit_length);

byteone numberofchannels;
byteone movebytes;

numberofchannels = little_endian_to_bytefour((table+22),NUMCHANNELS);
sizeofdata = little_endian_to_bytefour((table+40),SUBCHUNK2SIZE);
movebytes = numberofchannels * 2;
```

You are assigning an `unsigned int` return value to an `unsigned char` variable, so part of the value will be discarded. It just so happens that in this case the part that is left over is zero.

It's not clear what intended to happen here. Did you simply mean to declare the variables to have the type `bytefour`?

If you had compiled with warnings enabled, you should have been alerted to this potential problem.